Create test bean for a JpaRepository
I have a Spring Boot application halfway through migrating from old style Hibernate DAOs using a SessionFactory to Spring's JpaRepositories.
The problem I am facing is that in unit tests, I have some tests on an old Hibernate DAO that also join on a new table that is now a JpaRepository. Previously, I would've just @Autowired all the Hibernate DAOs declared as test beans and do whatever operations I desired. Now, I can't do that anymore, because I cannot autowire a JpaRepository into such a Hibernate DAO test.
More in-depth, I have a configuration on Hibernate unit tests that declares repositories like:
@Bean
public SomeDao someDao() {
    SomeDao someDao = new HibernateSomeDao();
    someDao.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
    return someDao;
}

For my new JpaRepositories tests, I use the following configuration:
    @DataJpaTest
    @ContextConfiguration(initializers = TestContainersInitializer.class)
    @AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE) // use Testcontainers 

Now, what I need to do, is to be able to autowire a JpaRepository in a class annotated for the first use case, namely for the Hibernate DAO tests. For context, I am also using Testcontainers. What I have tried is creating a new configuration class annotated with the @DataJpaTest stuff and create there a bean for the new JpaRepository, which I would then import in the old test class as a Bean, but it was of no help. I think you cannot annotate a @TestConfiguration class with @DataJpaTest.
Bottom line, my question is: how can one create a test bean for a JpaRepository?

I think what you are looking for is @DataJpaTest annotation. This annotation helps spring boot to setup a testable environment for JPA repository.
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@DataJpaTest
public class TestJpaConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public YourJpaRepository yourJpaRepository() {
        // below you create an instance of your JpaRepository or mock it for 
        testing purpose
        return Mockito.mock(YourJpaRepository.class);
    }
}

Now use @SpringJUnitConfig(TestJpaConfiguration.class)  for writing DAO test.
  import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
  import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringJUnitConfig;

  @SpringJUnitConfig(TestJpaConfiguration.class)
  public class HibernateDaoTest {

    @Autowired
    private SomeDao someDao; // Autowire the DAO

    @Autowired
    private YourJpaRepository yourJpaRepository; // Autowire the JpaRepository

    // Write your tests here
  }

You might also need to use @AutoConfigureTestDatabase as per your need.
hope this helps.
